# App does not use full width of screen (Actionbar)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am facing a problem when it comes to the width of my app (attachment). It seems that the full width of the screen is not used since I am using a actionbar, and that the space where the "Settings" menu would appear is taking the remaining width of the screen. Is there any way to use the full width since I am not using the "Settings" menu anyway?

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.simple.activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

current_fragment.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.simple.fragments.Notifier">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tab_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <include android:id="@+id/layout1"
                    layout="@layout/activity_hour_notification"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></include>

                <include android:id="@+id/layout2"
                    layout="@layout/activity_minute_notification"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></include>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for any help on this one!

[image]

Comment: Post your layout xml code to get a better idea.

Comment: @abhilnair: Added. Let me know if there is more information that is needed.

Comment: Ok, let me ask where have you binned your fragment view in content_main.xml. Because your relative layout in content_main.xml is blank, Kindly justify. and one more thing, are you getting your layout under toolbar properly because you have not specified that in your include layout nor you have mentioned below "what" should the included layout should come. Please post your entire screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave width and height constant to the layout, for ConstraintLayout `match_parent` give 0dp and add all necessary constraints

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I set the android:layout_width="0dp" which solved the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In content_main.xml please use width match_parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.simple.activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Upvote as  android:layout_width="match_parent" also worked!

Answer (score 0):

use `LinearLayout` instead of `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` and set `orientation = "vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_fragment"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

here you make width with specific value not match parent and the fragment layout which contain toolbar and tab will take that width so you should make width of master_fragment match_parent or at least use toolbar on content_main.xml before relativeLayout